# What is the best practice in managing version name/code of a flutter app in a git repository linked to Visual Studio App Center for automated builds?

Tags: git, flutter, version-control, pull-request, visual-studio-app-center

We plan to configure our iOS and Android applications on App Center to trigger the build process automatically on every push to their respective UAT/Production branches (e.g. a push to the UAT branch should trigger the build for the UAT version of the flutter app for both iOS and Android).

Both iOS and Android builds are configured to use version number and build number from `pubspec.yaml`.

In a typical scenario where I would have 1 UAT version and 1 Production version of the app built (e.g. `1.2.0+11` for UAT and `1.2.0+12` for Production), how should I go about managing the changes to version and build numbers in `pubspec.yaml`?

For example, if I approved a pull request on UAT branch to build `1.2.0+11`, completed the testing and wanted to move it forward to Production branch to build `1.2.0+12`, would I have to create another branch (let's call it XYZ branch) to merge UAT branch to and modify the version and build numbers to `1.2.0+12` before submitting a PR from XYZ branch to Production branch? This is done so that there is only 1 push to the Production branch as the build process on App Center is triggered by a push to a specific branch.

Comment: "Best practice" questions generally belong on softwareengineering.stackoverflow.com.